# C++ I need to be able to resize my dynamic array

Tags: c++

I have this code of a dynamic array that I turned in as a lab. My instructor responded saying "wouldn't even compile, no resize of the array". I am having trouble dealing with the comment of "no resize of the array", meaning I have to add the ability to resize the array. Please help quick! (It does compile). Appreciate it.

I am supposed to make a program that asks the user to initially size the array. Create an array based on that size asking for a number, and insert the number. Then repeat getting and inserting a number, resizing the array as needed or until they enter -1 for the number.
Print the list.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int count;
    cout << "How many values do you want to store in your array?" << endl;
    cin >> count;
    int* DynamicArray;
    DynamicArray = new int[count];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cout << "Please input Values: " << endl;
        cin >> DynamicArray[i];

        {
            if (DynamicArray[i] == -1) {
                delete[] DynamicArray;
                cout << "The program has ended" << endl;
                exit(0);
            }
            else {
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) {
        cout << DynamicArray[k] << endl;
    }

    delete[] DynamicArray;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: User first inputs the count of the array, and it won't change after array has been created, so you don't need to resize the array. Why do you want to resize it ?

Comment: My instructor directions for this lab was: Ask the user for how big to initially size the array.
Create an array based upon that size.
Ask for a number, insert that number into the next unused place in the array.
Repeat getting and inserting a number, resizing the array as needed or until they enter -1 for the number.
Print the list.  I turned in the code I had and he responded, "wouldnt even compile, no resize of array"

Comment: Think about the problem. You first create an array at the requested length then add elements to it until it's full then you need to make a longer new array and copy the elements from the earlier one. Then delete the first and replace it with the second and add more numbers. Rinse and repeat until the -1. Think about how to code it. It's likely designed to instill appreciation for `vector`

Comment: So there's possibility that user inputs 10 values even when user answers 5 to "How many values do you want to store in your array?"

Answer (score 1):

When the array is full, we need to resize it. Here is my solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int count;
    cout << "How many values do you want to store in your array?" << endl;
    cin >> count;
    if (count <= 0) {
        cout << "The value should be greater than zero" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    int* DynamicArray;
    DynamicArray = new int[count];

    int i = 0, value = 0;
    while (1) {
        cout << "Please input Values: " << endl;
        cin >> value;

        if (value == -1) {
                cout << "The program has ended" << endl;
                break;
        }
        else if (i < count)
        {
            DynamicArray[i++] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            // resize the array with double the old one
            count = count * 2;
            int *newArray = new int[count];
            memcpy(newArray, DynamicArray, count * sizeof(int));
            delete[]DynamicArray;
            newArray[i++] = value;
            DynamicArray = newArray;
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        cout << DynamicArray[k] << endl;
    }

    delete[] DynamicArray;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ahh ok. When I tried to compile it in code blocks, I got the error line 35: 'memcpy' was not declared in this scope.

Comment: @M.Cow add "#include <cstring>". I updated the source code. please check again

Comment: For when it asks how many values do I want to store, for example, I input 4. But it allows me to infinitely input as many values after and doesn't output the values. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @M.Cow Please following the requirement of instructor, until you press -1, the loop will be stopped and print the output

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, you're right. I understand now. thanks so much.

Comment: A reasonable solution and the code almost documents itself with good identifier names so little explanation of the code is required. +1. Take care though that you don't do too much of people's homework. You do not want to have to work beside someone who has cut-n-pasted their way through most of their programming courses.